# creating a big dropdown menu with zurb foundation

Tags: zurb-foundation

How to create a mega-menu bar using foundation5. I need it for creating menus having a giant collection of submenus specially for ecommerce websites.

Answer (score 0):

You have an example on the [doc](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html), the first top bar is displayed with sub menu, sub sub menu ...